java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission " "com.mysql.cj.disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup" "read")
I was trying to connect to a database in my web project using JDBC, but it throws
Error:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "com.mysql.cj.disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup" "read")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:488)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:411)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1146)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:966)
    at java.base/java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Boolean.java:283)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.<clinit>(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:57)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:77)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
    at com.server.Register.doPost(Register.java:29)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:124)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.lambda$execute$0(SecurityUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.lambda$doFilter$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:124)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

I have tried to resolve this exception using ChatGPT. I have used this code snippet from ChatGPT, but to no avail.
System.setProperty("com.mysql.cj.disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup", "true");

Using:

JDK 21
Tomcat v10.1 server

package com.server;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

@WebServlet("/Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String sql = "insert into login_credentials values(?,?,?)";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/personal_finance";
        String user_name = "root";
        String dpassword = "Pavan@999";
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String user_id = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println(email + " " + user_id + " " + password);
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user_name,dpassword);
            PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            smt.setString(1, user_id);
            smt.setString(2, email);
            smt.setString(3, password);
            int i = smt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.print(i + " " + "records inserted");
            con.close();
            response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}

Can someone tell me to resolve this issue?

Can you tell me why did you try to add a system property instead of a security constraint?

i'm don't know chatgpt told me to do soo and i did.(i'm a beginner)

If you get a problem with security manager, and you didn't do anything against it, then probably you have a problem with the installation.

does that mean i have to reinstall eclipse?

Chatgpt should advise you not to use Chatgpt.  But it probably isn't smart enough :-)

ChatGPT told you to set a system property, but it didn't tell you how. You have tried to set it at runtime but it requires to do it on startup.

Regular Google would have gotten you to https://www.cnblogs.com/wtsgtc/p/14295068.html, which more or less guides you to enumerating that permission in your JRE's java.policy file--assuming there's not a version of the MySQL driver that doesn't require this kind of modification.

The problem is that you have written a code which has a connection leaks. The code might not close a connection when an exception occured. Probably you miss to check the request parameters for null values. To properly close a connection you should use try-with-resources which auto-close a connection. You can read more about this here Does creating and closing database connections each time I need them have any effect?
You might also disable disableAbandonedConnectionCleanup thread if you set a system property of JVM when it initially started with -D switch. This bug is described here Bug #96870.
